# Zeitwerk::NameError due to Module name in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I recently upgraded my application from rails 6 to 7 and I am facing one issue due to zeitwerk naming convention. I have a below file which I want to autoload:

```
app/models/dw/hospital.rb

module DW
  class Hospital < DataWarehouse
    def self.columns
      super.reject{|column| column.name == 'tableau_user' }
    end
  end
end
```

I tried autoloading this file by adding the following line in my `application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_once_paths << 'app/models/dw'
```

But when I am starting the server I am getting the following error:

```
expected file app/models/dw/hospital.rb to define constant Hospital, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
```

I'm not sure why this is throwing such error since the constant is already defined. I suspect it is because the module I have defined before the class. Please let me know if anybody how to fix this. I have been stuck at this far too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've added `app/models/dw` to autoload paths, you have to define `Hospital` but your definition is namespaced `DW::Hospital`. You don't need to touch autoload config, `app/models` is already in `autoload_paths`:

```rb
>> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
=> 
...
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/jobs",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/mailers",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/models",   # <======
...
```

These are so called [*root directories*](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#root-directories-and-root-namespaces). It means file structure relative to `app/models` have to correspond to module/class names.

So if you have `dw/hospital.rb` in any of the root directories you have to define `Dw::Hospital`, which you've defined already. You have to watch for inflections as well, it should be `Dw`, unless you have an acronym inflection rule or *zeitwerk* inflection:

```
>> "dw".camelize
=> "Dw"

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "DW" 
end  

>> "dw".camelize
=> "DW"
```

---

If you must [nest root directories](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#nested-root-directories), you should have a really good reason:

```rb
# if you want it to be reloadable,
# use `autoload_paths` instead of `autoload_once_paths`
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app/models/dw")

# app/models/dw/hospital.rb
class Hospital
end
```

But as Xavier mentioned in the comment, there is no need for this configuration. Use the default config and don't complicate your set up unnecessarily.

Comment: Excellent answer. Let me add, to be clear, that there is no need to touch the configuration (please do remove that config.autoload_once_paths setting), and that this is covered in the migration HOWTO: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#acronyms

Comment: Alex and @XavierNoria Thankyou for you answer, it was really helpful. Although I had another question related to zeitwerk. Please answer if you know something about that. I have been stuck at this rails 7 upgrade for quite a while now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73754260/zeitwerk-not-autoloading-models-in-rails-7

Comment: I answered that other question .

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem with uppercase

Normally `PascalCase` (aka `CamelCase`) class name must correspond to the `snake_case` file name. The same rule applies to namespaces and folders

But you have `DW` in `dw` folder (not `Dw`)

You can create some initializer like this

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb 

Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector = Zeitwerk::Inflector.new
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    'dw' => 'DW',
    # other special cases
  )
end
```