# Zeitwerk not autoloading models in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I recently upgraded my Rails version of my application from 6.1 to 7 and I am facing one issue with zeitwerk. I was also using the zeitwerk in my rails 6.1 which was working fine but suddenly something is breaking when I upgraded it to rails 7.

Since zeitwerk automatically loads root directories so it must autoload the models as well. But now when I try to initialise a model when booting up the server I am getting `uninitialized constant` error.

```
>> "user".camelize.constantize
=> `constantize': uninitialized constant User
```

I also checked this `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` and it included the path `"app/models"` but still it gives the `uninitialized constant` error and I am not sure why.

However I tried adding the following line to my `applicatio.rb` file

```
config.autoload_once_paths << "app/models"
```

and then it gave me an error saying that zeitwerk was loading the same directory twice and then I had to add this line in the `config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb` file in order to make it work.

```
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("app/models")
```

At first it seemed to have fixed the problem but later it resulted in multiple test failures.
So my question is that is there something I need to add in my `application.rb` file in order to make it work in rails 7?

Below is a snapshot of my `application.rb` file if that helps.

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 7.0
    config.autoload_once_paths << "app/models"
    config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false
    config.assets.enabled = false
    config.api_only = true
    config.version = Dir.pwd.split('/').last
    config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false
  end
```

Comment: I'm assuming you upgraded using the `bin/rails app:update` task? Is there something weird in your `new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb` file?

Comment: `config.autoload_once_paths << "app/models"` I don't sure you need it. Where do you define `User`? May be you have few classes with such name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to the configuration. Please do not change `config.autoload_once_paths` or any autoloading configuration.

As explained in the [upgrading guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization), in Rails 7 you cannot autoload constants when the application boots. Your application on Rails 6 was already issuing warnings about this with instructions about how to address them.

Please follow the instructions in the upgrading guide to fix it.